# Is this a good way for proving $A - B \subseteq A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm asked to prove $A - B \subseteq A$ and would like to verify if my proof is well-written, correct, and see how I can improve it.

**Proof:**

For $A - B \subseteq A$, we would need that $$\forall x(x\mid x \in (A-B) \to x \in A).\tag{$i$}$$

Since $A - B = \{ x \mid x \in A\, {\rm and }\, x \notin B\}$, we know that $A - B \subseteq A.$

If we return to $(i)$, we are left with the implication that $\forall x(x \in A \to x \in A)$, which is true.

Therefore, $A - B \subseteq A $.

---

Is this a good way for proving this? What other elementary method could I use to analyze this problem, since I'm still staring to learn this subject?

Comment: Formulas are not correct. Subset relation needs $\to$ instead of "and".

Comment: Could you explain what is $(i)$ in your question, and why is there an 'and' there? Also, it is wrong to write $A-B \in A$, perhaps you meant $A-B \subset A$.

Comment: Second line proves that $A \setminus B \subseteq A$ (instead of $\in$).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: The errors are typos. I didn't type it correctly as was written in my notes, it has been edited. The tutorial helped a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Well, a proof using quantifiers explicitly requires more knowledge about first-order predicate logic.

Informally you can get rid off the all-quantifier by saying ''$x$ is an arbitrary element''.

Then $x\in A\setminus B$ means that $x\in A\wedge x\not\in B$.
Here you can infer that $x\in A$, since the implication $P\wedge Q\Rightarrow P$ is a tautology (and for the mathematicians here one needs modus ponens as well).

Answer (score 2):

*Here's an alternative proof . . .*

We have $x\in A\setminus B$ iff both $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$. But, surely, if both $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$, then, in particular, $x\in A$. Thus $A\setminus B\subseteq A$.

Comment: Exactly! Keep things simple!!

Answer (score 0):

$C\subset A \iff \forall x\in C x\in A$

$x\in A\setminus B \iff x\in A \land x \notin B \Rightarrow x\in A$

Keep caution that $C\subset A$ is not equivalent to $C\in A$

Answer (score 0):

[Edited]

The expression :

> $\forall x(x\mid x \in (A-B) \to x \in A).\tag{$i$}$

would read maybe  : for all $x$, the set of all $x$ such that if $x$ belongs to $A-B$ then x belongs to $A$

The expression " for all x" needs a sentence in its scope, not a set. Note also that the set builder notation *already contains an implicit " for all $x$ ".*

It seems to me that what you wanted to do was to show that the set of all $x$ satisfying the inclusion condition was identical to the universal set $U$ ; which is equivalent to saying that $A-B$ is included in $A$ , or,  that any $x$ belonging to $A-B$ is also a member of $A$.

What you could do, in order to follow this line of thought,  is this, using

$\bullet$ $ (x\in S \land x\notin S) \equiv x\in \emptyset$  ( For all set $S$)

and

$\bullet$ $ (x\in \emptyset \land x\in S) \equiv x\in\emptyset$ ( For all set $S$)

and finally the idea that

$\bullet$ $ \forall (x) \phi(x) \equiv  [\{x|\neg \phi(x)\}=\emptyset] $ :

> $\{x| \neg ( x\in A-B \rightarrow x\in A)\}$
>
> $=\{x| \neg [ (x\in A \land x\notin B) \rightarrow x\in A]\}$
>
> $=\{x| \neg [ \neg (x\in A \land x\notin B)\land x\notin A]\}$
>
> $=\{x| \neg [ \neg (x\in A \land x\notin A\land x\notin B]\}$
>
> $=\{x| \neg [ \neg (x\in\emptyset \land x\notin B]\}$
>
> $=\{x| \neg [ \neg x\in\emptyset]\}$
>
> $=\{x| x\in\emptyset\}$
>
> $= \emptyset$

since the set of all $x$ that do not satisfy the inclusion condition ( namely : $ x\in A - B \rightarrow x\in A$ )  is equal to $\emptyset$, it means that any $x$ satisfies this condition :

$\forall (x) [ x\in A - B \rightarrow x\in A ] $

and therefore that

$\ A-B \subseteq A$.

---

My first attempt made use of  a universal set U , but was not reliable. See comments below.

Comment: "any element of the Universal set" ... eh? you have to assume there is a universal set to prove that −⊆?? Really???

Comment: @PeterSmith.- Please , charity principle in interpretation! I did not say that what I did was the only way to proceed. i said that one could proceed in this way, assuming one wants to assume there is a universal set. What is wrong wtth this assumption in the context of set algebra?

Comment: futhermore, I wanted to show the OP that there was a way to follow his original line of thought.

Comment: You don't need to suppose there is a universal set to make sense of the OPs line of thought.

Comment: My idea was to translate the expression $ \forall (x)\ \phi (x)$ into $\{x|\phi(x)\}=U$ ( for I saw the OP had inserted the $\phi(x)$ sentence - the one that defines inclusion - inside the set expression).  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @PeterSmith. Could the edit I have done dispense me with the (-1) ?